# Stylized jquery table plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, dynatable

I'm quite taken with dynatables' stylized list. I was wondering whether anyone knew of any plugins with similar capabilities to style results in that way. I've had a look into datatables but haven't found examples of it working in this way.

https://www.dynatable.com/#a-stylized-list

Many thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap CSS for easily implemenation.

You can find [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content).